# Mongodb: Change value of a key in a nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure(simplified) of data:

```
{
quiz_id : ObjectId(),
questions : [{
      question : "xyz",
      options : [{
           option_text : "a"
           },
           {
           option_text : "b"
           }]
      }, {
      question : "pqr",
      options : [{
           option_text : "s"
           },
           {
           option_text : "t"
           }]
      }]
}
```

Now I want to add update this by adding `answer_count : 0` to each option.
So new data structure is:

```
{
quiz_id : ObjectId(),
questions : [{
      question : "xyz",
      options : [{
           option_text : "a",
           answer_count : 0
           },
           {
           option_text : "b",
           answer_count : 0
           }]
      }, {
      question : "pqr",
      options : [{
           option_text : "s",
           answer_count : 0
           },
           {
           option_text : "t",
           answer_count : 0
           }]
      }]
}
```

How to do this in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the documents to add the `answer_count` and the use `db.save()` to update the document.

```
db.foo.find().forEach(function(doc){
    for(var question of doc.questions) {
        for (var option of question.options) {
            option.answer_count = 0;
        }
    }
    db.foo.save(doc);
})
```